# Newsfeed gives 404

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

The Newsfeed in the top ribbon keeps giving me 404 the news feed picture of what I select. [image: The error]

Comment: If it is the top ribbon that is to do with My Sites. Have you created a MySite site collection?

Comment: I have created a site collection, but I had assumed that once you create the main site collection that it was the central point for everything? Do you have to create a diffrent site collection that is attached to the same Web Application to use the NewsFeed?

Comment: My Sites are best placed into a web application of their own (although normally you have one auto-created in the base web application by the system). Once made it should auto link via the Newsfeed/OneDrive/Sites link in the top right corner.